# Traits with "#[openbrush::trait_definition]" cannot be referenced

Tags: ink, openbrush

- I want to implement a base contract that multiple contracts should implement.
- I decided to use "#[openbrush::trait_definition]" because "[#ink(message)]" cannot be added in the normal implementation of traits.
- However, traits declared in another library crate cannot be referenced.
- If you remove "#[openbrush::trait_definition]" as a trial, you can refer to it.
- Could you tell me what is wrong?

definition of trait: commons/lib.rs

```
    #[openbrush::trait_definition]
    pub trait Destination {
        #[ink(message)]
        fn execute_function(&mut self) -> Result<(), ()>;
    }
```

use of trait: destination_base/lib.rs

```
#[openbrush::contract]
mod destination_base {
    use commons::Destination;    
    /// Defines the storage of your contract.
    /// Add new fields to the below struct in order
    /// to add new static storage fields to your contract.
    #[ink(storage)]
    pub struct DestinationBase {
        /// Stores a single `bool` value on the storage.
        value: bool,
    }

    impl Destination for DestinationBase {
        #[ink(message)]
        fn execute_function(&mut self) -> Result<(),()> {
            self.flip();
            Ok(())
        }
    }
```

error:

```
    Checking destination_base v0.1.0 (/Users/shin.takahashi/develop/work/delegate_test2/contracts/destination_base)
error[E0432]: unresolved import `commons::Destination`
 --> src/lib.rs:9:9
  |
9 |     use commons::Destination;    
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `Destination` in the root
```

Comment: can you share github link to your code?

Comment: I guess you haven't include `commons  = { path = "../../commons", default-features = false }` inside dependencies of `destination_base ` cargo.toml. also don't forgot to include `"commons/std"` inside std

Comment: Thank you. I tried but The situation remains the same.I made a similar sample and pushed it below, could you check it out?　https://github.com/realtakahashi/trait_test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked on Element's BrushFam. And "Dominik | Brushfam" told me.
To fix this error you need to import everything. As below.

```
use commons::*;
```

trait_definition macro generates some code which is then used by the ink_contract so you need to expose that too in order to impl that trait for your contract

Answer (score 0):

I have added `contract/logics` in contracts because your `contract/commons` is different. I think you have generated this folder using `cargo new commons`? instead you can use `cargo contract new logics` command to create new contract. I have fixed your code. Include logics  = `{ path = "../logics", default-features = false, features = ["ink-as-dependency"] }` inside dependencies of test/Cargo.toml and include "`commons/std`" inside std. Aslo don't forgot to add "`rlib`" to the crate-type options under "cdylib" in your `logics/Cargo.toml`. I have [included github.com repo of the code](https://github.com/123oli/fix-code).

Comment: Thank you for your proposal of the solution. Your sample can be compiled, but the "execute_function" is not a contract function. I want to call "execute_function" as a contract function like the "flip" function. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean `execuate_function` Methods flagged with #[ink(message)] in `impl Base for test {}`?

Comment: yes,right. When I added "#[ink(message)]" to execute function, I got errors.

Comment: @s.Takahashi Instead of `#[openbrush::trait_definition]` if you use `[#[ink::trait_defination]]` it solves. I don't know why exactly it doesn't work with openbrush. You can view [changes here](https://github.com/123oli/fix-code/blob/e8b6c837271d8454b6f5285bb5af4746041a36d3/contracts/logics/lib.rs#L7)

Comment: Thank you so much. I understood this code could be compiled with "ink::trait definition".
But as you said, I can not solve compile error that I use "open brush::contract".
I will try to ask to openbrush team.

Comment: oh wow it fix, thank you @s.Takahashi